# NHibernate Insert Into Table

Tags: c#, nhibernate

How i can insert data to table with CreateQuery()?

c# class

```
namespace NHibernateTutorial
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public virtual int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }           
    }
}
```

mapping xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                assembly="NHibernateTutorial"
                namespace="NHibernateTutorial">
  <class name="Customer">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="CustomerId">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="FirstName" />
    <property name="LastName" />    
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My program class

```
    var configuartion = new Configuration();
                configuartion.DataBaseIntegration(x =>
                    {
                        x.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=NH;Initial Catalog=NHibernate;Integrated Security=False;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False";
                        x.Driver<SqlClientDriver>();
                        x.Dialect<MsSql2012Dialect>();
                        x.LogFormattedSql = true;
                        x.LogSqlInConsole = true;
                        x.AutoCommentSql = true;
                    });

                configuartion.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

                var sessionFactory = configuartion.BuildSessionFactory();
                using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
                { 
                 var query = session.CreateQuery("INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName) select i.FirstName, i.LastName from CustomerOld i"); 
                 query.ExecuteUpdate();
                }
```

In this example i copy row from another table, but i need create new row, how i can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer here is: this is not supported. Check the [13.3. DML-style operations](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct), an extract:

> The pseudo-syntax for INSERT statements is: INSERT INTO EntityName
>   properties_list select_statement. Some points to note:
>
> - Only the INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... form is supported; **not the INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... form**.
>     ...
> - select_statement can be any valid HQL select query
>     ...

The idea behind DML is that you do manipulation directly on the DB side. For insertion the values must be there (somewhere).

**But** there **is** solution for your case, use the standard way:

```
var customer = new Customer();
customer.FirstName ...
session.Save(customer);
```

That's correct approach, and will do what you need

Could be interesting reading: [NHibernate – Executable DML](http://ayende.com/blog/4037/nhibernate-executable-dml)